# How can we check the balance of any substrate account if we have its key?

Tags: polkadot

With https://www.rinkeby.io/#explorer, we can check the balance of any Ethereum address.

Is there any tool/portal for substrate address, where we can check the balance of any substrate account?

Comment: Are you looking for an explorer? https://www.subscan.io/

Comment: Thanks. I was looking for same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common way is using [Polkadot Apps](https://polkadot.js.org/apps/?rpc=wss%3A%2F%2Frpc.polkadot.io#/chainstate).

Because we can not ensure every chain has integrated with Subscan service, and sometimes you are under a development environment.

---

Example:

Navigate to `chain state` > `system` > `account` > `type in the address` > `submit`.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I got the answer. Its subscan.io